# Add a workbook once and paste the data in the same workbook on subsequent runs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet (sheet2) which contains a vlookup function with changing values in certain cells to refresh data. I want to copy any changed values to another workbook.

```vb
Sub Copy_file()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("C6:M124")
    Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    Rng.Copy
    xWs.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    xWs.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    xWs.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    xWs.Cells(2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

Every time the code runs it creates a new workbook.

I need to modify it so that I can add a new workbook with a specific name and the copied data is pasted in sheet1 only when the macro runs for the first time.

On subsequent runs the copied data should be pasted in the next sheet (e.g. Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4,... etc.) in the single workbook.

Comment: Do you like the workbook in discussion to use the **next sheet** all the time you use it? I mean, should it do that only after opening it and running being open? Or doing that continuously, independent of the moment of opening? If the last scenario, please test the code I posted. If you need it to work so only at each opening, please state it and I will adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like the first scenario you've offered. do you have a solution?

Comment: Please, check the version I posted after editing the answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Copy_file()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, Rng As Range, wb As Workbook, wsMark As Worksheet
    Dim wbFullName As String, wbName As String, lastR As Long
    
    wbName = "MyWorkbook.xlsx"
    wbFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbName
    
    Set Rng = Range("C6:M124") 'the range is set in the active workbook
                               'if the one keeping the code, please state it
                               'and the range will be fully qualified
    If dir(wbName) = "" Then 'if the necessary workbook does not exist
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add 'create it
        wb.saveas wbName                   'name the newly created workbook
        Set wsMark = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
        wsMark.Name = "UsedSheets"         'name the last sheet keeping copying order
    End If
    If wb Is Nothing Then                  'if not created above, but exists:
        On Error Resume Next
         Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)        'check if it is open
         Set wsMark = wb.Worksheets("UsedSheets") 'set the sheet keeping copying order
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    'if not open, open it:
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)
        Set wsMark = wb.Worksheets("UsedSheets") 'set the sheet keeping copying order
    End If
    lastR = wsMark.Range("A" & wsMark.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last used row in the sheet
    If lastR > 1 Then
        If CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value) < (wb.Sheets.count - 2) Then
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets(CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value + 1))
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        Else
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wsMark)
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        End If
    Else
         Set xWs = wb.Sheets(1): wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = 1
    End If
    Rng.copy
    With xWs.cells(2, 2)
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
   End With
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next variant. It open a new workbook, first time you run the code and uses it until you close it. You **must manually save it, when finished the copying process**...

```
Sub Copy_file()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, Rng As Range, wb As Workbook, wsMark As Worksheet
    Dim wbFullName As String, wbName As String, lastR As Long
    
    wbName = "MyWorkbook.xlsx"
    wbFullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbName
    
    Set Rng = Range("C6:M124")
    If dir(wbName) = "" Then 'if the necessary workbook does not exist
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add 'create it
        wb.saveas wbName                        'name the newly created workbook
        Set wsMark = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count)
        wsMark.Name = "UsedSheets"         'name the last sheet keeping copying order
    End If
    If wb Is Nothing Then                        'if not created above, but exists:
        On Error Resume Next
         Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)      'check if it is open
         Set wsMark = wb.Worksheets("UsedSheets") 'set the sheet keeping copying order
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    'if not open, open it:
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)
        Set wsMark = wb.Worksheets("UsedSheets") 'set the sheet keeping copying order
    End If
    lastR = wsMark.Range("A" & wsMark.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last used row in the sheet
    If lastR > 1 Then
        If CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value) < wb.Sheets.count - 1 Then
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets(CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value + 1))
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        Else
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wsMark)
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        End If
    Else
         Set xWs = wb.Sheets(1): wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = 1
    End If
    Rng.copy
    With xWs.cells(2, 2)
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
   End With
End Sub
Sub Copy_file1()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, Rng As Range, wb As Workbook
    Dim w As Workbook, wsMark As Worksheet, lastR As Long
    
    Set Rng = Range("C6:M124") 'if active sheet belongs to the workbook keeping this code
                                            'it should be adapted to fully qualify the range
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then           'check if wb exists but it losts the reference because of an error:
        For Each w In Workbooks  'iterate between open workbooks:
            If w.Sheets(w.Sheets.count).Name = "UsedSheets" Then
                Set wb = w
                Set wsMark = wb.Worksheets("UsedSheets"): Exit For
            End If
        Next w
    End If
    'if wb does not exist:
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add 'open a new workbook and set  it
        Set wsMark = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count) 'set the last sheet like the one to keep copying order
        wsMark.Name = "UsedSheets"
    End If
    If left(Rng.Parent.Parent.Name, 4) = "Book" Then 'if, by mistake, the selection is done on a wb sheet:
        MsgBox "The active sheet where ""Rng"" was set belongs to the workbook where to copy..." & vbCrLf & _
                   "It should be a mistake. Please, select the appropriate sheet!", vbInformation, "Wrong sheet selected.."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    lastR = wsMark.Range("A" & wsMark.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last used row in the sheet
    If lastR > 1 Then  'for the first time (when wb has been created):
        If CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value) < wb.Sheets.count - 1 Then
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets(CLng(wsMark.Range("A" & lastR).value + 1))
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        Else              'if is not the first copying time:
            Set xWs = wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=wsMark)
            wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = xWs.Index
        End If
    Else
         Set xWs = wb.Sheets(1): wsMark.Range("A" & lastR + 1).value = 1
    End If
    Rng.copy
    With xWs.cells(2, 2)
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Copy_file()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Static WB As Workbook  ' static variables stores its values between proc calls
    
    If WB Is Nothing Then   ' check if a certain workbook exists. if no, create it
        Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    Else
        WB.Worksheets.Add after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count) ' create the next WS
    End If
    Set xWs = ActiveSheet
   
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C6:M124").Copy
    With xWs.Cells(2, 2)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I get the message "Run-time error '9'

Comment: Which line throws the error?